# Cannot mount a USB pendrive

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, mount

I have no problem to mount the USB pendrive from file browsers (Nemo, Nautilus, Dolphin, etc). But I have a pendrive, which cannot be mounted from the file browser. The error message is:

```
Not authorized to perform operation
```

And I found that it has a **harddisk** icon instead of **removable media** icon.

I can mount the pendrive with the root user with "mount" command.

Is there anyway to fix this problem so that pendrive will be recognised as the USB removable media instead of the harddisk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my pendrive was modified with Lexar BootIt, which flips the Removable Media Bit (RMB).

I am not sure which of the following steps recover the pendrive into the removable media instead of harddisk.

1. I dd out the 512 bytes of another normal pendrive (not the partition, but the device, eg: /dev/sdc).
2. Then I plug in the problem pendrive, and dd in the 512 bytes from step 1.
3. Then use gparted to create the partition table and also the partition with the FAT32.
4. Restart the computer.

Only after step 4, I found that my pendrive is detected as normal removable media.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can have many different origins. The most likely one is that you have a problem with **polkit**. Do you have a directory called */etc/polkit-1/localauthority*? If so, edit, as root, this file: */etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/55-storage.pkla* and add the following lines:

```
  [Storage Permissions]
  Identity=unix-group:plugdev
  Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-eject;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-detach;org.freedesktop.udisks.luks-unlock;org.freedesktop.udisks.inhibit-polling;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-set-spindown
  ResultAny=yes
  ResultActive=yes
  ResultInactive=no
```

You should also add yourself to the *plugdev* group,

```
 usermod -a -G plugdev <your username>
```

which is the correct command for Debian-family distros (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint,...), if you are not on one of those please adapt it to your distro.

If this does not apply, please report back.